# How to "stick" an object to another such that it follows during animation

Tags: animation

I am trying to animate a swimming robot. It looks like this[image: Swimming robot consisting of 4 big spheres, 1 center sphere and 4 thin connecting jacks]
I can easily calculate the centers of the spheres during one swimming strokes and set the keyframes accordingly. Now, is there a way to "stick" the jacks to its two corresponding spheres such that it deforms during the animation? The idea is that the spheres always stay connected. In reality, the arms would elongate and retract. More precisely, the spheres move along the axis defined by the jack around some initial length, while the whole structure translates and rotates.

Comment: Parent it with Ctrl+P.

Answer (score 5):

You may want the cylinders to keep their shape when the spheres are moving.

**First approach: cylinders follow spheres**

[image]

A way to do that is to use bones and a *"stretch to"* constraint for each bone:

[image]

The vertices of each cylinder are linked to there bone's group name.

Each bone is placed along its cylinder.

And each bone as a *"stretch to"* constraint to the sphere (with *"maintain volume"* to none in order to have no deformation of the diameter).

[image]

**Second approach: spheres follow cylinders**

If you prefer to rig/animate the cylinder and make the sphere follow, you can use a *"copy location"* constraint to the spheres:

[image]

For each sphere, indicate the armature to follow, then the bone and set head/tail ratio to 1 so that the sphere follow the tail of the bone.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have at least 2 methods:

**With hooks:**

To hook the cylinder to the sphere: select the sphere, shift select the cylinder, go in *Edit* mode, select the top edge loop and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to Selected Object*, now when you move the sphere it stretches the cylinder.

[image]

Then when you animate you just move the sphere along its local axis:

[image]

**With bones:**

You can use one unique object (sphere + cylinder), or 2 separate. Create a bone at the center of the sphere, parent the object to the bone *With Empty Groups*. Select the object, go in *Edit* mode, select the vertices that are supposed to be controlled by the bone, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, select the group and click *Assign*:

[image]

To animate, switch the armature to *Pose* mode and move the bone. Create the other bones within the same armature. The advantage is that you can more easily create and control your animations, for example you can use the bone axis to make the sphere follow the correct axis, and you can reset the armature to its rest pose.

[image]

Comment: But I cannot do that with both spheres right?

Comment: But as soon as I parent the jack to the other sphere, the parenting to the first sphere is deleted. Furthermore, how can I make the jack actually _elongate_ when the two spheres move away from each other?

Comment: oh ok my bad, you can do it with a hook, I'm going to edit, but maybe show in your original post what kind of animation you'e planning to do

Comment: Okay, I'll edit!